# How to float image like this?

Tags: css

I did it guys..
but why one picture don't want to float left...
is it because I delete my height on the column?
because I think the height is not important here.

[Should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSKl4.jpg)

I hope they float like my photo above ^

```css
.column img{
  width: 100%:;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-1.png">
      </div>
       <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-3.png">
      </div>
     <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-4.png">
      </div>
       <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-2.png">
      </div>
     <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-5.png">
      </div>
    
    
       <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-6.png">
      </div>
     <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-7.png">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="images/gallery-8.png">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a working pen or snippet so that anyone can edit and check it out

Comment: Why don't you create a three column layout?

Comment: @AravindReddy okay wait a minute

Comment: This is a grid layout, it uses `flex` and has nothing to do with floating.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović so, every image have different grid?

Comment: What he's suggesting is basically a grid layout just with fixed 3 columns. A grid layout defines your content in rows / columns so making something like this is fairly simple. Grid layout -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout .Column layout -> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp

Comment: AnteJablanAdamović well thanks mate, i'll try.

Comment: I just need suggestion to build it actually, what method should i try. i'll try it :)

Comment: Note that columns are currently more widely supported than grids, and in a more standardized way.

Comment: I almost there, please help me guys AnteJablanAdamović, @MohammadUsman,